# Delete users through ProxyModel of custom User model

Tags: django, python-2.6

My django project implements a custom user model (MyUser). It also implements a proxymodel (MyUserProxy) for my custom user, and I want to use the proxymodel to delete users from my database. See the model & manager below,

*project/account/models.py*

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models    
from .managers import MyUserManager

class MyUser(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    ...

    objects = MyUserManager()

    class Meta():
        verbose_name = _('My user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('My users')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

class MyUserProxy(MyUser):

    class Meta():
        proxy = True
```

*project/account/managers.py*

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager

class MyUserManager(UserManager):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyUserManager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Several other apps inside my project have ForeignKey relationships with my custom user (MyUser) and thus when I delete a user, the records related to that user also get deleted. When I specify the AUTH_USER_MODEL in my settings.py to be MyUser then this works just fine and records from related apps get deleted with the user.

*project/example/settings.py*

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.MyUser'
```

However when I use MyUserProxy for the AUTH_USER_MODEL, I get an error,

```
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'otherapp.myuserproxy_id'
in 'where clause'")
```

Django seems to think that the ForeignKey database column for the app "otherapp" is "myuserproxy_id" whereas it actually is "myuser_id" since the model MyUser specified it. Why does django relate the name of my proxymodel (MyUserProxy) to the database column ?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, my otherapp model has a ManyToMany relationship to the AUTH_USER_MODEL. ManyToMany relationships get the column name derived from the proxymodel name (myproxuuser_id) whereas ForeignKey relationships get the column-name derieved from the model being proxied (myuser_id). Otherapp uses migrations and thus change in column name "myuser_id" did not occur resulting in the OperationalError. For clarification I have put the models and the resulting database structure below,

project/X/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ()
    'A',
    'B',
)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'A.Aproxy'
```

project/A/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'field1'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['field2']

    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(A, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class AProxy(A):

    class Meta():
        proxy = True
```

project/B/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from A.models import A

class B(models.Model):

    a = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    mtm = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='mtm')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Results in the table structure,

```
A_a
+----+--------+--------+
| id | field1 | field2 |
+----+--------+--------+

B_b
+----+------+--------+--------+
| id | a_id | field1 | field2 |
+----+------+--------+--------+

B_b_mtm
+----+------+-----------+
| id | b_id | aproxy_id |
+----+------+-----------+
|  1 |    1 |         1 |
+----+------+-----------+
```

Why django applies a different column name for ManyToMany fields it not clear to me though.